# Unable to locate package ros-groovy-desktop-full error on fresh precise

Tags: ros, package, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a fresh install of precise that does not find the ros package even though the same apt-get command works find on a non-fresh ubuntu precise system.

When I use cat /etc/apt/sources.list, the following shows up:

`See http//help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
newer versions of the distribution.`

`deb http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise main restricted universe multiverse`

`Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
distribution.
deb http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse`

`Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
repository.
N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise universe
deb-src http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise universe
deb http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates universe`

N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-backports main restricted
deb-src http//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-backports main restricted

Note that the colon in the web addresses has been removed to allow myself to post the contents.

I have updated my keys and apt-get database per the installation wiki's instructions. I do not know what else is going wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54967/unable-to-locate-package-ros-groovy-desktop-full-error-on-fresh-precise/) by [Drendude](https://answers.ros.org/users/4180/drendude/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Drendude](https://answers.ros.org/users/4180/drendude/) on 2013-02-11**:
Please note that there is no installation of ROS already on this machine. This error occurs while trying to install it with the command:    sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a problem in the ROS repository.
So you need to set up your repository to

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ahendrix-mirror/ubuntu precise main
```

You will also need to use a different package name, because
"ros-diamondback-desktop-full"
is not in the repositories.

*** Warning: I do not know the differences between the packages below, and ros-diamondback ***

I am able to install ros-groovy-ros or ros-groovy-ros-full
Maybe those packages will work for you.

---

Originally posted by [Beel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4781/beel/) with karma: 26 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1